# Cannot resolve dimensions in main_activity.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I'm following a tutorial to help me build a 2D game - https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-game-development-tutorial-1/#Planning-the-Game-Story

The tutorial tells me to add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/splash"
tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.simplegame.MainActivity">
```

But I'm getting cannot resolve errors on the following:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

I've tried ALT+Enter to create a dimen.xml file, but I'm not sure what to even put when doing this and my app will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Do not have the dimen file
You must create one and place the data in your educational video
Or change the code to this:

```
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
```

Put the number in the tutorial video you're following to get the correct numbers instead of the written number `0`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, I hit ALT+ENTER to create a dimen.xml file, I then put the value as 0dp for each.